# How to find the column index number based on "Name Box" value in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to process excel columns based on Named cell (instead of A1,A2 the cells are renamed to be retrieved independently irrespective of column placement)
I have tried to get the Named Range but not able to get the column Index.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [Name](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Name.html) object of the named range, you can get the [RefersToFormula](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Name.html#getRefersToFormula--) from that.

Having this you can get the cell reference of the first cell in that refers to formula. This is the tricky part because a `RefersToFormula` can be a `AreaReference` too. So I would first try to get it as [CellReference](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html). If that fails, try get it as [AreaReference](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/AreaReference.html). If that succeed the get the `CellReference` via `AreaReference.getFirstCell`.

Having the `CellReference` you can get column index via `CellReference.getCol`.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ExcelGetNamedCells {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Workbook.xls"));
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Workbook.xlsx"));

  String nameName = "";
  String nameRefersTo = "";
  CellReference nameFirstCellReference = null;
  AreaReference nameAreaReference = null;
  short nameFirstColumn = -1;

  for (Name name : workbook.getAllNames()) {

   nameName = name.getNameName();
   System.out.println("Name of named range is: " + nameName);

   nameRefersTo = name.getRefersToFormula();
   System.out.println("Named range refers to : " + nameRefersTo);

   // get cell reference of first cell in refers to formula
   nameFirstCellReference = null;
   try {
    nameFirstCellReference = new CellReference(nameRefersTo);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    // do nothing. nameFirstCellReference stays null
   }
   if (nameFirstCellReference == null) {
    nameAreaReference = null;
    try {
     nameAreaReference = new AreaReference(nameRefersTo, workbook.getSpreadsheetVersion());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
     // do nothing. nameAreaReference stays null
    }
    if (nameAreaReference != null) {
     System.out.println("Area reference of named range is : " + nameAreaReference);
     nameFirstCellReference = nameAreaReference.getFirstCell();
    }
   }

   if (nameFirstCellReference != null) {
    System.out.println("First cell reference of named range is : " + nameFirstCellReference);
    nameFirstColumn = nameFirstCellReference.getCol();
    System.out.println("First column of named range is: " + nameFirstColumn);
   }
  }

  workbook.close();

 }
}
```